# InAppPurchases not working on PhoneGap App

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins

I'm having some problems trying to get running inAppPurchases inside my iPhone phoneGap-based app.
I got the inAppPurchase-plugin on gitHub https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager

Then i created my developer account, purchased de u$d 99, and made my inAppPurchase Catalog
Created my iTunes Connect account to get a Test User for this.

I placed all the plugins file where it says... And, if i try to run "alert(typeof window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager)" it shows "object" so, plugins are being loaded correctly!

The problem appears when i try to do my purchase..

I logout my itunes account, run my binary inside my iphone, and when i make the purchase i should see a prompt asking me for my test account information in order to make a symbolic purchase! But it never happens!

The javascript code (very basic) im trying to run is the following

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(event) {
    window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onPurchased = function(transactionIdentifier, productId, transactionReceipt) {
        alert("purchased");
    };

    window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onRestored = function(originalTransactionIdentifier, productId, originalTransactionReceipt) {
        alert("restored");
    };

    window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onFailed = function(errorCode, errorText) {
        alert("error");
    };

    window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.requestProductData(
        "com.mycompany.myproduct.myproductid", 
        function(productId, title, description, price) {
            alert("data retrieved");
            window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.makePurchase(productId, 1);
        },
        function(id) {
            alert("Invalid product id: " + id);
        }
    );
}
```

Hope you can help me! thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to call js functions like window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onPurchased in html.index for these functions to work.i.e these functions call onPurchased in js and correspondingly it will call obj-C functions.

(js function in index.html)->(js function in js file)->(objective-C function)...is the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any invalid product ID's back? There are a lot of gotchas on Apple's end. Try reading through [this guide](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) to find what you need to get the product info request to return valid products.